# export more than one ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: ros, catkin-ws, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I had source my catkin_ws as suggest me in this question:
http://answers.ros.org/question/66084/catkin_make-package-not-found/?answer=66117#post-id-66117
but when I roslaunch my launch file the other package are't found.

I had create the ws inside the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH following this tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace how can I export both path?

thanks guys

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66145/export-more-than-one-ros_package_path/) by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried extending your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` after sourcing the catkin workspace? Like with:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-06-28**:
Thanks for the answer @felix k , I tryed to add that line on my bashrc but without results, soo I added this line:  source /home/master/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash to bashrc and it works. but I don't know if it is the correct way...

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-06-29**:
Uhm, sourcing that file was exactly the suggestion from Jeremy in that other question, what have you actually done? Anyway, this would be the ideal line for your `.bashrc`, my export line would only be needed for another or a rosbuild workspace. I don't see what you meant by 'other package'.

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-07-01**:
Sorry, I mean other rosbuild package like the node for the motor driver.